# I have a PIL image in a Numpy matrix that has negative values. How could I save it?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I converted a PIL image into a 3-dimension Numpy matrix, but the values of each pixel go from -1.88 to 3.36. How could I save it into a png file?

Comment: How did you get these negative values? Did you modify the pixel values?

Comment: I am using Facenet, and those are the values that are returned when you load a face using it, but in reality it uses PIL.

Answer (score 1):

You could rescale your matrix to lie in the range of 0-255. Example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([-1.20, 2.81, -1.88, -0.03, 3.36, 2.01])
a_min = np.min(a)
a_max = np.max(a)
a_scaled = 255*(a-a_min)/(a_max-a_min)
print(a_scaled)
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't know where those values come from and what they mean.